# Kubenetes Ingress API Routing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have a react web application listening on the default path and I'm looking to include my API backend on the same URL.

A snippet of my ingress is below:

```
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: atsweb
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: atsapi
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```

My API has a bunch of functions which are routed after /api/ and I have a test page at mydomain.io/api/values which I cannot get to. My frontend service works fine.

Is it just the pathing which is incorrect?

I've deployed a standalone API just to check the container port/service ports are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you copied the example from . What are your ingress annotations? Check the rewrite as it looks like is making a redirect. Nonetheless, the ingress that would work for looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: your-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: atsweb
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/
        backend:
          serviceName: atsapi
          servicePort: 80
```

Check there is no rewrite annotation. This makes your uri be appended fully to the next proxy. Thus, making `mydomain.io/api/values` go to `atsapi:80/api/values`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that answer. Apologies I didn't put the whole ingress. Wasn't sure how critical that was! This and the removal of 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1' got it working. Thank you for the explanation of the URI appends.

Comment: @Koxzi , As with all other Kubernetes resources, an Ingress needs apiVersion, kind, and metadata fields; however, Ingress frequently uses annotations to configure some options depending on the Ingress controller, an example of which is the rewrite-target annotation. 
Different Ingress controllers support different annotations. 

If anyone needs comprehensive info on rewrite-target, that can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md)